# lost the vertical scroll function in touchpad after upgrading from 13.04 to 13.10

Tags: 13.10, mouse, sony, scrolling

just upgraded from Ubuntu 13.04 to Ubuntu 13.10, my Laptop is a Sony SVE1512c6ew, scrolling worked perfectly in Ubuntu 13.04, doesnt work at all in 13.10

Runs Ubuntu 13.10 64bits (btw, tested it i Windows 8 environment works there)Hardware OK, have seen a number of other users with the same problem, well for starters have followed the tip on using the dconf editor, following the path:

org > gnome > settings-daemon > peripherals > touchpad
boxed in all for sure... still cant get vertical scroll......

Any ideas???

Thanks in advance

---

Input device information according to Udev:

```
Input device
Subsystem: input
Devtype: n/a
Name: input7
Number: 7
Sysfs_path: /sys/devices/platform/i8042/serio1/input/input7
Driver: n/a
Action: n/a
Seqnum: n/a
Device type: n/a
Device number: 0
Device file: n/a
Device file symlinks: n/a

Touchpad device
Subsystem: input
Devtype: n/a
Name: mouse1
Number: 1
Sysfs_path: /sys/devices/platform/i8042/serio1/input/input7/mouse1
Driver: n/a
Action: n/a
Seqnum: n/a
Device type: char
Device number: 3361
Device file: /dev/input/mouse1
Device file symlinks: /dev/input/by-path/platform-i8042-serio-1-mouse
```

Answer (score 1):

ck. in either dconf-editor > org > gnome > settings-daemon > peripherals > touchpad & see if `scroll-method` is set to `edge-scrolling`. If not do so & see.

Or System Settings > Mouse & Touchpad, make sure `two finger scroll` is disabled

Comment: The second option works for me