# Ubuntu GNOME 16.10 - unable to enable vertical scroll using side of touchpad

Tags: gnome, touchpad

I upgraded to Ubuntu GNOME 16.10 from 16.04.  I have an HP Laptop with a touchpad.  **Previously you could scroll using the right hand edge of the touchpad, but no longer**.  I can only use two-finger scroll, and I don't like it, it also tends to not work that well.

I tried similar instructions to [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/264091/enable-horizontal-scrolling-in-ubuntu) and [this one too](https://askubuntu.com/questions/372061/lost-the-vertical-scroll-function-in-touchpad-after-upgrading-from-13-04-to-13-1), but the "touchpad" option is missing in dconf-editor under the following tree:

```
org > gnome > settings-daemon > peripherals > touchpad
```

I have installed `gnome-tweak-tool` for Gnome 3.20 ([using these instructions](https://github.com/zpydr/gnome-shell-extension-taskbar/wiki/TaskBar-Installation#github-repository)), but it has no options available either.

Any ideas how to get scrolling using the edge of the touchpad?

**UPDATE 1:**

I looked under

```
org > gnome > desktop > peripherals > touchpad
```

and the settings were available.  But the `scrolling` parameter was already set to `edge-scrolling` (see image below), but it does not seem to work.

[image]

**UPDATE 2:**
I created a new user.  Because they would have fresh settings and would show that my settings may be slightly corrupt.  But the new user has the same issue.

Comment: don't use 16.10 but maybe have a look in /org/gnome/desktop/peripherals/touchpad and /mouse

Comment: @doug thanks, I looked under `/org/gnome/desktop/peripherals/touchpad` and `mouse`, and I found the settings, but that did not help.  I have updated the question with a screenshot.  And I like near-bleeding-edge and this is my only issue with 16.10 at the moment.

Comment: I see that ubuntu-gnome 16.10 is using xserver-xorg-input-libinput. Apparently those dconf  options won't apply to libinput. If that's the case you can either try installing xserver-xorg-input-synaptics & removing   xserver-xorg-input-libinput, after a reboot edge would likely work. Otherwise you'd need to research how to affect changes to libinput, I looked at that some time ago but atm don't remember. (creating a file somewhere... maybe

Comment: maybe look here - https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Libinput though also read here - https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/89443/how-to-enable-touchpad-edge-scrolling/

Comment: @doug, awesome, and thanks a lot.  That last link you provided did the trick.  If you write up the answer I will accept it.  I used the exact steps as on the ask Fedora page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Libinput on X11 workaround.  This was taken directly from [ask.fedoraproject.org](https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/89443/how-to-enable-touchpad-edge-scrolling/).  This is what made it work for my Ubuntu GNOME.

There is a workaround for libinpunt on X11:

1) Determine ID of your touchpad, for me it was the `SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad` with id of `11`:

```
xinput list
```

2) Create desktop file in `~/.local/share/applications` named `edge-scroll-workaround.desktop`.  This creates the `edge-scroll-workaround` application.

```
vim ~/.local/share/applications/edge-scroll-workaround.desktop
```

3) Place here this code in the `edge-scroll-workaround.desktop` file:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Edge scroll workaround
Exec=/usr/bin/xinput set-prop **ID OF TOUCHPAD** "libinput Scroll Method Enabled" 0, 1, 0
Type=Application
```

4) In Tweak Tool (available in gnome-tweak-tool package) go to Startup Applications, click on + and in list find Edge scroll workaround.

5) Run `edge-scroll-workaround.desktop`, I do this by clicking the Super key and typing `edge-` and the application should appear.  Logout/login or restart and that's it.

Answer (score 0):

Go to settings and go to this section:

**Org** > **Gnome** > **Desktop** > **Peripherals** > **Touchpad**

Once you are there, change **natural-scroll** to ***false***.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work for me.